# I have a menu and I don't how to use proprely slideToggle, to slideDown and slideUp when i pressed another li from ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function for main menu :

```
$('.main-menu-left > li > div').each(function(){
    if( $(this).next('.sub-menu').length ){
        $(this).on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('li').find('.sub-menu').slideDown('slow'); 
        });
    }
});
```

And a function for slide up menu:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
    if( $('.sub-menu').is(':visible') ){
        $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
    }
});



<ul id="menu-left" class="main-menu-left">
<li>
    <div class="group-menu"><span>Browse</span><a id="first-li"><p class="menu-text"><i class="icon-small-arrow-gold"></i>Blinds</p></a></div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">                                                               
            <li><a href=""><span>Explore</span><u>+</u>Wooden Blinds<b>(18 collections)</b></a>
                <ul class="list-products">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                <li><a class="title">Next day<p class="details">no Samples of Verticals Blinds</p></a></li>
                                <li><a class="title">Blackout<p class="details">96 Samples of Verticals Blinds</p></a></li>
                                <li><a class="title">Pattern<p class="details">120 Samples of Verticals Blinds</p></a></li>
                                <li><a class="title">Wipeable<p class="details">30 Samples of Verticals Blinds</p></a></li>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                                <p class="text-explore">&explore all <s>Vertical Blinds</s> </p> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                          
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Explore</span><u>+</u>Venetians Blinds<b>(20 collections)</b></a></li>
        </ul>                                       
    </li>
 <li class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"><a><p class="menu-text"><i class="icon-small-arrow-gold"></i>Roman</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is html code, for my menu.

It's opening and closing simultaneously. And how can i do to close an li and open other on click ?

Comment: would you please share your html code as well?

Comment: And a demo would be more beneficial.!

Comment: `$('body').on('click'` is wrong way to collapse an element if user clicks anywhere else on the viewport

Comment: do you wnat like when the li is slided down, and u click outside the li anywhere it should slideup??

Comment: Yes i want to slide up when i click outside the li.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind as different functions so that you can unbind the body click and the fire the slide open, slide closed separately. This is how I would write it:

```
//Wrap it in a function to avoid conflict. Pass in menu as an object we will use inside
(function ($, menu, undefined) {

    //this is the initialiser function
    menu.init = function() {

        //Store the subNavs as a jQuery array so we can loop them
        var subNavs = $('.sub-menu');

        //Check there are members in the array
        if( subNavs.length > 0 ){

            //for each member run the initialiser
            $(subNavs).each(function(i, subNav) {

                //Select the head of the sub-menu in the DOM. In this case it is a sibling
                $(subNav).siblings('.group-menu').on('click', function(e){

                    //prevent the default action of the click and stop it propagating up to the body
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    //test if this is an open menu or closed and send each one to a different handler
                    if ($(subNav).hasClass('open')) {
                        menu.clickOff($(subNav));
                    }
                    else {
                        menu.clickOn($(subNav));
                    }

                });
            });
        }
    };
    menu.clickOn = function(el) {

        //set the element as 'open'
        el.addClass('open');

        //bind the body click handler
        $('body').on('click', menu.clickBody);

        //Do the slide down!
        el.slideDown('slow');

    };

    menu.clickOff = function(el) {

        //set the element as not 'open'            
        el.removeClass('open');

        $('body').unbind('click', menu.clickBody);

        //Do the slide up!
        el.slideUp('slow');

    };

    menu.clickBody = function(e) {

        //check if the target is the open menu item itself or part of it
        if ($(e.target).closest('.sub-menu.open').length == 0) {

            //If not, pass it through to the close handler
            menu.clickOff($('.sub-menu.open'));
        }
    };

    //call the initialiser() on page load
    menu.init();

}(jQuery, window.menu = window.menu || {}, ""));
```

You can view the fiddle of this here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/h6Xnb/2/

Hope it helps.